# How to set Microsoft Exchange Appointment Private programmatically?

Tags: c#, outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

I am using Microsoft Exchange 2010 and i want to set appointment privacy grammatically

**Code:**

```
Appointment appointment;
if (notes != null)
{
    var mtgBody = notes[0];
    var meetingBody = StripHtml(mtgBody.Note);
    appointment = new Appointment(service)
   {
       Subject = meeting.Subject,
       Body = meetingBody,
       Start = Convert.ToDateTime(meeting.StartTime),
       End =
           Convert.ToDateTime(meeting.StartTime.Value.AddMinutes(30)),
   };
```

I am not able to find any property here which will set privacy for appointment.

[image]

Comment: There's a program called Outlook Spy that might help you. http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm

Comment: @RenniePet Thanks for your reply, and let me check

Comment: I have a program that processes Outlook appointments on the Exchange Server itself. Once the appointment gets sent to Exchange as a MAPI object the private property is represented by a MAPI property with ID PR_COMMON_PRIVATE, 0x8506. Don't know if that's of any help for what you're trying to do when interacting directly with Outlook.

Comment: Am i able to use it in C#? All works fine except privacy so if possible then please tell me for this Appointment class

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about the Outlook interface. Dmitry Streblechenko, they guy behind Outlook Spy, sells an interface program for Outlook called Outlook Redemption http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm . I'm quite sure that would let you do what you want to do. But it may not be necessary. Dmitry is very active and helpful on several Outlook forums, and can probably tell you.

Comment: Ok then will find some another solution and thanks for your help